# Game Center causing UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center, uiinterfaceorientation

I have checked other solutions to this problem and none have worked for me.

If I try to authenticate a GKLocalPlayer on my physical iPhone (*not the simulator; this works in the simulator*), I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has
no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x373463e7 0x33d7e963 0x37346307 0x3815b857 0x382fff21 0x381dfcdd
0x381def6b 0x37349ad4 0x372a128f 0x382fd0f3 0x32acce01 0x30a19793
0x30a195db 0x30a1ce45 0x3731a1b1 0x3728d23d 0x3728d0c9 0x315d733b
0x38147291 0x101a73 0x1019d0)
```

I have tried to add the following code to the view controller, but nothing changes:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

This application is only supposed to run in landscape and I can confirm that it only happens when I try to authenticate a player through Game Center. If I take that line out, there are no problems.

**EDIT**

To clarify, this happens when the following code runs:

```
- (void)GKLogin
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {
            NSLog(@"Authenticated");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Not Authenticated");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: To clarify, is this when you register a new player account? That view does require portrait and if you constrain it to landscape will raise this exception. No way around this.

Comment: This is when I run `[localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {`.

Comment: I have never had this problem before. I used the same code in another app that is only landscape and this flag never came up.

Comment: Aha, that's pretty general and shouldn't happen.

Comment: So what do I do to fix it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in application delegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

return (NSUInteger)[application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:window] | (1<<UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

Comment: Does this go in `ViewController.m`?

Comment: Hooray! Thank you! Accept in 4 minutes :)